# How to add pre-hashed password to ejabberd with ansible

Tags: password, ansible, password-management, ejabberd

I know that I can add users using the ansible [ejabberd_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ejabberd_user_module.html) module, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add a user with a pre-hashed password.

I want this:

```
- name: create a user if it does not exists
  ejabberd_user:
    username: test
    host: server
    password: password
```

to look like this

```
- name: create a user if it does not exists
  ejabberd_user:
    username: test
    host: server
    password: 2eAJBXOqN7PeM # or whatever possible hash
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Add the functionality to the module and submit a pull request.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but the issue actually seems to be that I can't find anything in the ejabberdctl docs that even say you can add users with hashed passwords. Maybe this can't be done, but I'm hoping it can be and that someone out there knows about it more than I do.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to securely create active users from ansible.

Comment: How do you define "securely"? What's the attack vector?

Comment: The server is provisioned by an ansible script shared via a git repo amonst a group of friends. We would want to put the password for our account there without each other being able to see it, hence the need for a hash.

Comment: Don't put passwords in git repos or use Ansible Vault.　・　Besides... "**our** account" and "securely" don't match.

Comment: Sorry, *accounts. And there's a reason for Ansible Vaults. It's useful. I'm not really here to argue that though, I'm here for an answer concerning already established tech. Also, keeping a _hashed_ password should be secure enough for my purposes. I just don't know how to do that, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible in the current version of ejabberd.